# Automator task to open screenshots in Preview automatically

Tags: terminal, applescript, automator, preview, screen-capture

I'm pretty new to Automator but it seems like it's possible - I just can't seem to get it to work.

I'd like to be able to take a screenshot and then open it up in Preview for easy annotation. *If it's possible I'd then like to copy it to clipboard after saving but that's not 100% needed.*

I've tried following a few articles but never received good results. The one that got me closest is here: https://andytaylor.me/2014/05/22/better-os-x-screenshots-with-shell-scripts/

I don't need Dropbox so I edited that part out and I modified it based on some other suggestions - here's what I have:

```
directoryname="Screenshots"
filename="shot_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').png"
path="$HOME/Pictures/$directoryname/"
mkdir -p "$path"
screencapture -o -i "$path$filename"
open -a 'Preview' "$path$filename"
```

When I run the [Automator task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK5uB.png) it says that it was completed successfully but it just opens up Preview, it doesn't even allow me to do a screencapture. When I copy/paste into Terminal [it hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TghrZ.png) on the last line - but successfully allows me to do the screencapture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Feanux I was answering your question and then you deleted it but I see you reposted it, anyway I have made a Automator app that does this and will attach a screenshot (that was taken by Automator).[image]
As you can see it takes two screenshots, one for clipboard and one for preview/save

### UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Since they're interactive screenshots it prompts me to just take 2 screenshots automatically and doesn't open Preview :(

Comment: I'm uploading a screen capture of this working, give me a sec...

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/13mzxw87b22zp2k/screen.mov

Comment: Did it work for you? If so could you mark my question as correct :)

Comment: Works great if I want to do a fullscreen screenshot but I need to make it interactive to be choose the selection. Changing the "Type" to Interactive means I now have to take the screenshot twice and choose the same selection both times.

Comment: I'll have a try at changing it give me a moment :)

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Looks great! I think that will work, didn't think it would be that simple. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, I've taught my self all this with **minor** help from Google, so it's always good to share my knowledge and I expanded on it a bit too (never used the screenshot task before or the preview one)

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of that confirmation pop-up? When executing the workflow always states "Please select an area to take a screen shot."

Comment: I'll try, no promises since I just woke up